# Basic problems: Bootstrap templates displayed wrong Grails 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, grails-3.0

I am pretty new to Grails/ Bootstrap/ HTML and webprogramming in general. I am not an IT-guy but I have to implement a little monitoring website for a research project. I am pretty sure there is a simple solution to my problem - I would really appreciate if someone could help me!

I am using IntelliJ with Grails 3 and I am trying to integrate the SB Admin2 Bootstrap template from Start Bootstrap into my project.

My problem is, that the Website is not displayed as it should. First I tried to follow this tutorial http://grails.asia/how-to-apply-a-commercial-bootstrap-theme-to-your-grails-application/ but it didn't work for me - don't know where I failed. Then I just copied the index.html content into my gsp file. First only the text was shown, then I followed an answer from this post [Bootstrap template not getting displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883900/bootstrap-template-not-getting-displayed) and added a link to BootstrapCDN  - It worked.. but not correctly. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOzsY.png)

Now the head of my layout gsp file looks the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 -Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Hope someone can help me!
Thank you in advance!

edit1: If I use the IntelliJ preview in the html file it works perfect.

Comment: [This](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) is the template I want to use.

Comment: Did you check your console if you have any errors like 404 ?

Comment: It takes bootstrap css link and other css it doesnt load.

Comment: @Shahil I there are no errors.. Can you explain your second comment? Thx!!

Comment: As you are using bootstrap from external its is loading fine. I am not sure if your other css reference link is works.

Comment: The other links are right from this Startbootstrap template. As I edited in my post, the IntelliJ html preview works fine and the result looks like it is supposed to. Furthemore the Menu defined in an css file is displayed.. not correctly but displayed. Thus I believe the other reference links work. I think something goes wrong during the compile process. 
Do I need to add any plugins or something? I thought grails is able to handle bootstrap templates by default..

Comment: Once you view your web page in the browser, Can you right and click on view source.. It will list all your css files. right click on css file and open in new tab to confirm the files are loading or not.

Comment: Thanks for this hint.. When I open the css file in a new tab the same source code (the code of the layout gsp) opens again. I think that indicates that my files are not loaded correct - right? Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: what i recommend is put all your css files in the root and then reference the file. that would be easier for time being.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I saw you use relative paths in your links to the javascripts etc.

```
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would prefere to use absolute ones like

```
    <link href="${request.contextPath}/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I use a few Bootstrap-Layouts in different Grails Applications (in one application even the sb-admin). Let me try to explain my way (btw. seems that it's nearly the same as your first link, but another description might help out a bit) ...:

- copy the index.html to views->layout->main.gsp
- place the e.g. g:layoutBody in apropriate places in the main.gsp page and remove the elements which are not useful for your app.

  ```
  <div id="page-wrapper">
      <g:layoutBody/>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
  ```
- copy the javascripts, images etc. to the web-app directory and check the references in the main.gsp layout that they refer to the javascripts etc. via

  ```
  <script src="${request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  ```
- after that, your views could look like this:

  ```
  <%@ page import="urlaub.Employee" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta name="layout" content="main">
          <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'employee.label', default: 'Employee')}" />
          <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <g:if test="${session.user.admin}">
              <div class="row">
                  <g:link class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link>
              </div>
          </g:if>
          <g:render template="/flash_message" bean="${flash}" />

          <div class="row">
              <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
              <hr>
          </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. Unfortunately I am still not able to get it working. 
I did the first to tasks. Not sure what I am supposed to do with the 3rd task. I added the startbootstrap files to a file named "jarvis" like the tutorial I posted said. 
The result is pretty much the same.. The bootstraps don't work. If I use <code> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script> <code>

Comment: ahh.. didnt finish my comment, sorry. 
Adding the link to the bootstrapCDN enables the bootstraps as before, but it still doesnt look like it supposed to. 
Do I have to move the CSS or JS files to another directory? Sorry for this lack of basic knowledge!

Comment: Do you have a public repository somewhere of your code or could you create one - maybe with a shortened/stripped version, that I can have a look at it?

Comment: https://github.com/Jonas1234567/SB_Admin.git
here is a short version where I just tried to integrate the bootstraps as I tried in my original project. Would be very nice if you could have a look at it :)

Comment: Got it running. The web-app directory is gone in grails3, therefore I have to use src/main/resources/public directory. It should be possible to use the asset-logic, but that's something where I currently have no knowledge. Hope it helps a bit. I created a pull-request for your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 comes with Asset pipeline plugin to manage static assets, minimize them, etc,...
Check [its documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/). In your case you should move your assets to the corresponding asset folder (javascripts, stylesheets, images) into de assets folder.

For example, for including a css placed in assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css you have to include in you gsp the following:

```
<asset:stylesheet href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Other example with javascript and assetPath:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${assetPath(src:'register.js')}"></script>
```

Comment: I added the whole bootstrap template with all css, js and html files to the asset file. For that I created a new file within the asset file - like this tutorial told me: http://grails.asia/how-to-apply-a-commercial-bootstrap-theme-to-your-grails-application/

Comment: has you checked that all assets are embbed in the html, into the navigator debugger ?